# Best way to calculate remaining build percentage via API in Jenkins?

Tags: json, jenkins

Using a URL based call to retrieve build status on Jenkins - what is the cleanest and easiest way to calculate % remaining on a build?

I have looked at using `estimatedDuration` with `timestamp` from the returned JSON and then calculating that against server's current timestamp, but I am having issues because my calling servers timestamp is off by a bit from what the jenkins server `timestamp` is (not to mention TZ differences and the servers are hosted with different providers / I cannot fix the problem with the timestamps directly).. beyond that it seems a bit loose to rely upon two different servers timestamps to calculate anything if it can be avoided..

ADDITIONAL INFO:
The Jenkins JSON url I am using is in this format: `http://{jenkins_serverurl}/job/{jenkins_job_name}/{jenkins_job_number}/api/json`

It contains the `estimatedDuration` and (job start) `timestamp` referred above.  I am trying to use this for realtime display of estimated % remaining when Jenkins is building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy way to track the builds is from the jenkins public (on my config) ajax calls for viewing the HTML version of the build queue and the executors. It's the actual HTML of the progress bar. The percentage is found as an inline CSS attribute. Specifically, what you want to look at is the executors which is found at this endpoint:

```
POST /ajaxExecutors HTTP/1.1
Host: [JENKINS URL]
Content-Length: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: [JENKINS URL]
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
X-Prototype-Version: 1.7
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: [JENKINS URL]
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: [COOKIE INFO IF YOU NEED IT]
```

You get back an HTML representation of the progress bar. The critical part you want to look for is this:

```
...
<td class="pane">
  <div style="white-space: normal">
    <a href="/job/jenkins_cron/">jenkins<wbr>_cron</a>
    <table class="progress-bar" style="cursor:pointer">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="progress-bar-done" style=
              "width:17%;"></td>

          <td class="progress-bar-left" style=
              "width:83%"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</td>
...
```

What I would do is pull out the `style` associated with the `td` under the "progress-bar-done" class. You can use something like:

```
h=[ajaxExecutors RESPONSE BODY]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
found = soup.find("td", { "class" : "progress-bar-done" })
# -> <td class="progress-bar-done" style="width:17%;"></td>
percent_progress = re.findall( 'width:([0-9]+)%', str(found))[0]
# -> 17
```

NOTE: that you will have to parse the tr table when multiple builds are running. Also, there's no error checking, so if a build isn't running, you'll need to handle that case separately.